# Is there a TYPO3 brute forcer?

Tags: authentication, typo3, brute-force

A javascript aware one.

The one on Metasploit does not work:
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/typo3_bruteforce.rb

Answer (score 0):

If an "official" brute force exist the TYPO3 team try to fix this fast.

If you forgot your login you can create an new admin account over the install tool.